# HTML5 required attribute on Laravel (blade) doesn't work

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, required

This is my very first question, i think it's kinda stupid question but I need your help.
I'm working on a project right now, and i'm kinda stuck on a veeeery little problem. It seems like the input fields on my form are ignoring the required attribute. Anything else is workin but this one!
Here's the piece of code:

```
{!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'es. Paolo Rossi', 'required']) !!}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way: `required` is an input attribute. So it can be as follows:

```
{{ Form:: text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) }}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: Nothing.. the result is: <input class="form-control" required="" name="name" type="text"> and it's still doesn't work.